# Entity Framework 6, best strategy to get filtered data from big table with many links to other tables

Tags: c#, .net, entity-framework, linq, query-optimization

Which of these ways is better:

1. to perform 10000 small queries with filtration conditions to table linked with many other tables (we need data from linked tables too (doing .include() in LINQ expression)) or;
2. to get the data from the table and linked tables piece by piece without any conditions (in a loop, in 10 iterations => 10 queries to db), load them in a collection and then during every iteration perform all analytical work by LINQ with collection?

I think that second way will be faster but what about memory and how to solve this problem according to the rules of clean architecture?

Comment: No, lazy loading will not help. There is a city library: a table of users (each user has own term of keeping books) and this table links to the table of books with field when the book was taken. So, to get a list of expired books we should foreach(user in users) {select books where date < today - user.term} or probably select all users piece by piece and then work with the collection. Second way executed 4 times faster but it takes much memory and probably is a crutch solution

Comment: Second is better, but why without filters?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Neither of these two ways of solving the problem is look adequate.
If you suddenly got in the same situation like me, let`s exhale, drink tea, take a walk in the park.

Then try to rewrite the algorithm from the beginning. Almost certainly you can divide it onto the two parts:

At first, one query to db to filter out clients with whom you will work further.
That`s can look like:

```
var outdatedClients = db.Clients.Where(client => client.Orders.Any(order => order.Date < DateTime.Now.AddDays(-client.Term));
```

Then with `foreach (var client in outdatedClients){}` you can work with outdated orders by using `.include()` if it necessary. In most situations you can even avoid this cycle and get necessary data with one more query to db.